# Copy from one Access database to another (VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

I need help to copy data from one Access database to another using VBA. The tables have the same layout and the both have an autonumber Primary Key field.

I tried the following:

```
strSQL = "INSERT INTO [tbl_items] SELECT * FROM  [tbl_items] IN 'C:\temp\itemsdb.mdb';"
CurrentDb.Execute (strSQL)
```

The issue is that if the value of one Primary Key in first database is the same with one in the second database then that record is not copied.
Any ideas?

Comment: What do you want the database to do? Update the record? Assign a new value to the primary key? Something else? Obviously, there can't be two records with the same primary key, that's exactly the purpose of the primary key.

Comment: I would expect the value of the primary key of the source database to be ignored. Since the PK in the target is autonumber, the value of the key should be set there (in the target). So to answer your question the imported record should be assigned a new value.

Comment: Then, simply don't import the primary key. List all columns you do want to import in the query instead of using `SELECT *` which includes the primary key

Comment: I was wondering if there is an better way instead of writing a select of 60 fields just to exclude one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't even need VBA for this.  Try it this way.

1. On the External Data tab, in the Export group, click Access.

   Tip: You can also start the export process by right-clicking the object in the Navigation Pane and then clicking Export > Access.
2. Access opens the Export - Access Database dialog box.
3. In the File name box on the Export - Access Database dialog box, specify the name of the destination database and then click OK.
4. In the Export dialog box, change the name of the new object if you do not want to overwrite an existing object with the same name in the destination database.
5. If the selected object is a table, specify whether you want to export the table's definition and data, or only the definition.
6. Click OK to finish the operation.

If you really need a VBA solution, post back, and I'll provide a solution. In this scenario, it seems like VBA is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

It is a process that I wanted to automate because it is repeated quite often; so I needed a solution in VBA.
I found the solution that I share below for future reference.

```
 Public Sub AppendItems()
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim fDialog As Object
    Dim pickedFile As Boolean
    
    Set fDialog = Application.FileDialog(3)
    
    With fDialog
     
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        .Title = "Please select a file to import:"
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Access Databases", "*.MDB"
        
    End With
    
    pickedFile = fDialog.Show
    
    If pickedFile Then
        fPath = fDialog.SelectedItems.Item(1)
    End If
    
    strSQL = "INSERT INTO [tbl_DestinationTable] SELECT [field1], [field2], [etc] FROM [tbl_SourceTable] IN'" & fPath & "';"
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL (strSQL)
    
End Sub
```